# putting a password to pdf files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf

I am trying to create a website wherein, any person can upload a PDF, add a password and then, download it to the computer. So, when the person or anyone opens that PDF, the PDF would ask for the password. Right now, I got the upload, download and password fields. But, how can I protect the PDF with password? 
And, this application is with rails.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you please post some code you tried? how are you generating those pdfs?

Comment: I totally used this website:  http://richonrails.com/articles/allowing-file-uploads-with-carrierwave#.U77OF3Wx0nH

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using PRAWN gem for this ? It is pretty cool and will solve your problem/

Comment: I got the prawn gem but confused about what to do next. This is the hierarchy of files ---gem--gems--prawn-1.1.0--security--encryption.rb. I was thinking of changing this file: encryption.rb. Please help.

Comment: With prawn you can set a password when you create a pdf, not add a password to an existing pdf like the question is about.